# linking gwt combobox with database

Tags: database, gwt, combobox, gxt

I created a gwt app with a  gxt combobox. I have it where it pulls data (a list of names apprx 5000) from the database places it in an array which in turns places it in a store. That is then placed in the combobox using set store, so when a user starts typing in the combo it searches through the store for the name. My question: is this the best way to do this or is there another method.

Answer (score 1):

How is the performance loading that list of 5000 names?  Does it take a long time to load your page? You may want to think about loading them as you need them so that the gui loads faster.

This article suggest 'lazy loading' gui components
http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2008/11/improving-performance-with-on-demand.html

How have you pulled down the list?  I assume is via RPC, have you used a Data Transfer Object?, XML?

This link talks about options for serialization http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideSerializableTypes

Michael

Comment: I actually have not added the 5000 names yet, so I do not know what the performance will be like. I was concern about the performance which is why I wanted to know if the process I was using was correct. I'm new to GWT and wanted to follow the best method. I am using RPC, I'm not using xml, I have setup a simple DTO to move the results from the database to the client. I just created an object and dumped the results from the database into that object. I then returned it to the client. So do you think that once I add the lazy panel this would be a suitable method for GWT.

Comment: Your approach sounds ok to me, try rendering the results with a standard combo first, if you have performance issues look at lazy loading